# nginx critical error with SSL handshaking (routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:length too short) while SSL handshaking)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I have problem with my nginx on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. From time to time I get a critical error:

> 2018/11/17 20:35:20 [crit] 23322#23322: *291 SSL_do_handshake() failed
>   (SSL: error:1408A0A0:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:length too
>   short) while SSL handshaking, client: ******, server: 0.0.0.0:443

Why I get this error and how to fix that? Can it be dangerous?

Comment: Did you solve the mystery eventually? we are experiencing the same issue

Comment: Maybe there are users probably using and old android mobile browser or a webview of an old android phone for browsing, and because of server does not have support for SSL3. You can read more about it here: https://serverfault.com/questions/905011/nginx-ssl-do-handshake-failed-ssl-error1417d18cssl